# Transition probability between urn

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, solution-verification

> $N$ black balls and $N$ white balls are placed in two urns so that
>   each urn contains $N$ balls. At each step one ball is selected at
>   random from each urn and the two balls interchange. The state of the
>   system is the number of white balls in the first urn.

What I think

Let $X$ the number of white balls in the urn $(1)$ then we want $$P_{jk}=P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j)$$
then we have three possibilities for $k$ $$(i)\;k=j+1$$ $$(ii)\;k=j$$ $$(iii)\;k=j-1$$
First we know if $(1)$ have $j$ white balls then $(2)$ have $N-j$ white balls.

Let $A$ the event take a white ball in $(1)$ and $A'$ the event take black ball in $(1)$ then $$P(A)=\frac{j}{N}\space ,\space P(A')=\frac{N-j}{N}$$
analogous let $B$ the event take white ball in $(2)$ and $B'$ the event take a black ball in $(2)$ so $$P(B)=\frac{N-j}{N}\space,\space P(B')=\frac{j}{N}$$

Then we have for

$i)$ $$P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j)=P(A')*P(B)=\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right)^2$$
$ii)$ $$P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j)=P(A)P(B)+P(A')P(B')=\left(\frac{j}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right)+\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right)\left(\frac{j}{N}\right)=2\left(\frac{j}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right)$$
$iii)$ $$P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j)=P(A)P(B')=\frac{j}{N}\frac{j}{N}=\left(\frac{j}{N}\right)^2$$

Is that right? There is an easier way to do?

Comment: It feels like some kind of Dirichlet distribution. It is basicly some kind of stochastic process. It reminds to me to something that asked [some time ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275035/evolution-of-a-discrete-distribution-of-probability). Unfortunately I dont have the knowledge to ask your question but it seems very interesting.

Comment: Are you only looking for the transition probabilities?  Then in general outline the procedure is right. One can do it with fewer symbols.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If I were asked to write the matrix of transition, how could I do?In general I do not calculated the conditional, I just used the fact that $X_n=j$ and calculated intersections between two events, there is a direct way to calculate the conditional?

Comment: The transition matrix is in principle an $N+1$ by $N+1$ matrix.  It has in this case a relatively simple shape, it is a band matrix, with non-zero entries only on the main diagonal and the two "diagonals" just above and just below the main diagonal. There are as you knew three conditional probabilities to calculate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is right. For the transition matrix $(p)_{i,j}$, note that it suffices to determine the entries $p_{ij}$. wich are:

$$P_{jk}=P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j) = \delta_{(j+1)k}\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right)^2 + \delta_{j, k} 2\left(\frac{j}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-j}{N}\right) + \delta_{(j-1),k} \left(\frac{j}{N}\right)^2$$

Comment: @What this $\delta$ mean?

Comment: $\delta_{xy}= \begin{cases}1 & x=y\\ 0 & x\neq y\end{cases}$

Comment: Isn't this what the question states?

Comment: @Did What you mean?

Comment: That the values of the transition probabilities $p_{ij}$ are already written down in the question.

Comment: @Did Yes, these are the values I've ever found. To be honest I did not understand very well how he wrote the matrix.

Comment: Here is a summary of this page at present: *Question: I need to compute A and I have found that A=42. Is that right? There is an easier way to do? Answer: A=42.* Not sure I see the point of it all.